# Why does a program with Parallel::Loops exhaust my memory?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I've inherited some code at work i'm trying to improve on. My Perl skills are somewhat lacking so would love some assistance!

Essentially this script is SNMP polling a network of thousands of nodes to update it's local interface index cache. I've found it's hitting a problem where it's exhausting it's memory and failing. Code as follows (heavily reduced but i think you'll get the jist)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::Loops;

my %snmp_results;
my $maxProcs = 50;

my @exceptions;
my @devices;
my %snmp_results;

my $pl = Parallel::Loops->new($maxProcs);
$pl->share(\%snmp_results, \@exceptions );

load_devices();
get_snmp_interfaces();

sub get_snmp_interfaces {
    $pl->foreach( \@devices, sub {
        my ($name, $community, $snmp_ver) = @$_;
        # Create the new ifindex cache, and return an array reference to the new entries

        my $result = getSNMPIFFull($name, $community, $snmp_ver);
        if (defined $result && $result ne "") {
            my %cache = %{$result};
            print "Got cache for $name\n";
            # Build hash of all the links polled through SNMP
            # [ifindex, ifdesc, ifalias, ifspeed, ip]
            for my $link (keys %cache) {            
                $snmp_results{$name}{$cache{$link}[0]} = [$cache{$link}[0], $cache{$link}[1], $cache{$link}[2], $cache{$link}[3], $cache{$link}[4]];            
            }
        }
        else {
            push(@exceptions, "Unable to poll $name - $community - $snmp_ver");
        }
    });
}
```

This particular VM has 3.1GB of ram alloctable and is idling on about 83MB usage when this script is not running. If i drop the maxProcs down to 25, it will finish fine but this script can already take a long time given the sheer number of devices + latency so would rather keep the parallelism high!

I have a feeling that the `$pl->share()` is sharing the ever-expanding `%snmp_results` with each forked process which is definitely not necessary since it's not reading/modifying other entries: just adding new entries. Is there a better way I can be doing this?

I'm also slightly unsure about `my %cache = %{$result};`. If this is just creating a pointer as a hash then cool but if it's doing a copy, that's also a bit wasteful!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is the full code? It looks like `@devices` is has not been declared. The program should not compile. About `%cache`: it's declared inside of the `if`. _Lexical_ variables with `my` in Perl always live in the enclosing _scope_, which in this case is the `{}` block of the `if`. So in each iteration of the loop, it will create an entirely new `$result` and `%cache`, and GC will take care of them once they go _out of scope_. But the `%cache` is indeed not necessary. You can replace each `$cache{foo}` with `$result->{foo}`. I don't know about `share` though.

Comment: Yes, @devices is being declared, was just caught up in the slimming for this post. Sorry!

Comment: I'm also quite happy for alternative methods. The guy before me had been writing results to a database but since he had to open, write and close the database in each fork, it was often failing due to being unable to open files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation of the module can be found in the CPAN [here](http://search.cpan.org/~pmorch/Parallel-Loops/lib/Parallel/Loops.pm).

There's one part talking about the performance:

> Also, if each loop sub returns a massive amount of data, this needs to
>   be communicated back to the parent process, and again that could
>   outweigh parallel performance gains unless the loop body does some
>   heavy work too.

You are probably moving around complete copies of the variables in memory, pushing to the machine's limit if the MIB to poll and number of machines are big enough.

Since what you are doing is an I/O intensive task and not a CPU task that could benefit of parallel CPU processing, I would reconsider the approach of launching so many (50!) threads for polling.

- Run the program with `$maxProcs` down to 1 to 5 processes and see how it behaves. Do some profiling of your code, attaching `Devel::NYTProf` to check where you are consuming time and if increasing the number of processes actually leads to a better performance.
- Reconsider using `Parallel::Loops` for this task. You may get better performance with `use threads`[[1]](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) and a hash shared between the different threads (`use threads::shared`).

Apologies if this could have been a comment. Starting in SO is difficult due to all the limitations that are in place :(

If you already found a solution it would be great if you could share with us your findings. I didn't know `Parallel::Loops` before and I think I can give it some use.

Comment: Thanks for the info! For the record, my temporary solution was to throw a lot of RAM at it (which is hardly a solution but got it working for now). Extra RAM allowed me to keep the maxProcs high. CPU usage never gets very high and the high amount of maxProcs works well with the latency issues. Will look into threads and shared though :)